# What is the best approach to handle automated testing of iOS and Android in the same code?

Tags: appium, ui-automation, appium-android, appium-ios, automation-testing

What is the best approach to handle automated testing of iOS and Android in the same code?
I have to automate the same application on both iOS and Android platforms; the application looks almost the same on both platforms, except for the specifics of each operating system. What would be the best option to handle the tests in both?
Please let me know your suggestions.

Thanks,
Yani